# Convert JSON to a DataTable directly

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a Json(gridModel) which could be **a Json array or simple Json String.** I want to serialize it to a List which matches the Json. Using Newtonsoft.Json.

```
JArray jGridModel = JArray.Parse(gridModel);
List<ClassName> colModel = jGridModel.ToObject<List<ClassName>>();
```

This works fine if the gridModel is a JSON array, but if its a single JSON, it throws an error. Please assist.

**Another question. Instead of converting it to List, Is there a way to convert the JSONArray to DataTable directly, please help. Thanks.**

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the object generated by the code `JArray jGridModel = JArray.Parse(gridModel);` is a a **Type of List** See updated code below:

```
JArray jGridModel = JArray.Parse(gridModel);

// declare your output variable
List<ClassName> colmodel = new List<ClassName>();

// use var so it can accept any output type
var outputObject = jGridModel.ToObject<List<ClassName>>();

// check the type of the output
if (outputObject is ClassName){
   colmodel.Add(outputObject);
}
else{
   colmodel = outputObject;
}
//colmodel is your output which is always a List<ClassName> type
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out.